# Removing all line breaks and adding them after certain text

Tags: notepad++

I have text file in which I have to remove all line breaks, and later add new ones after each text `</row>`. how could I do that using replace tool?

Comment: What is "later", and what is "each text". How do you delimit the latter? An example would be welcome...

Comment: After removing all breaks, I need to add them, but only after text which is multiply definded in diferend places as  "</Row>"

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You need to that in two steps, at least.

First, click on the ¶ symbol in the toolbar: you can see if you have `CRLF` line endings or just `LF`.

Click on the Replace button, and put `\r\n` or `\n`, depending on the kind of line ending. In the Search Mode section of the dialog, check Extended radio button (interpret `\n` and such).
Then replace all occurrences with nothing (empty string).

You end with a big line...

Next, in the same Replace dialog, put your delimiter (`</Row>`) for example and in the Replace With field, put the same with a line ending (`</Row>\r\n`). Replace All, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me how to find several line breaks with data? That also has 4 empty spaces after line break? Like here I have 2: \n    daily ,\n    0.8

Answer (score 38):

You can also go to Notepad++ and do the following steps:

Edit->LineOperations-> Remove Empty Lines or Remove Empty Lines(Containing blank characters)

Comment: works, awesome useful when working with Ftp client that in some cases inserts you breaklines in your files

Answer (score 29):

You can also try this in Notepad++

- Highlight the lines you want to join (ctrl + a to select all)
- Choose Edit -> Line Operations -> Join Lines

Comment: Instead of using the menu, you can just use CTRL + J after highlighting the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 7):

- Open Notepad++
- Paste your text
- Control + H

In the pop up

- Find what: \r\n
- Replace with: BLANK_SPACE

You end up with a big line. Then

- Control + H

In the pop up

- Find what: (\.)
- Replace with: \r\n

So you end up with lines that end by dot

**And if you have to do the same process lots of times**

- Go to Macro
- Start recording
- Do the process above
- Go to Macro
- Stop recording
- Save current recorded macro
- Choose a short cut
- Select the text you want to apply the process (Control + A)
- Do the shortcut

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved this with following
Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL