# Convert multiple lines to single line using text editor

Tags: text, editor, cpu-word

I have the following words each in a line in a text editor

```
 'about', 
 'above',
 'across',
 'after',
 'afterwards',
 'again',
 'against',
 'all',
 'almost',
 'alone',
```

Can some help me to convert the above content into a single line using a text editor

```
'about', 'above', 'across', 'after', 'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone',
```

Comment: simply find `<br>` and replaceAll

Comment: @Abhishek <br> is not there. I added by mistake

Comment: You can refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989288/removing-all-line-breaks-and-adding-them-after-certain-text. I have also mentioned few methods in my answers that could you

Answer (score 3):

- #### Using Any Advanced Text Editor :

You could do it in some modern text editors that allow regex find and Replace. In such editors, you can do it using - Click on the Replace button and put `\r\n` or `\n`, depending on the kind of line ending (CRLF or LF). In the Search Mode section of the dialog, check the Extended radio button (interpret `\n` and such). Then replace all occurrences with nothing (empty string)

---

- #### NOTEPAD++ :

In Notepad++, you can do it as  :

1. Select the lines you want to join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all)
2. Choose `Edit` -> `Line Operations` -> `Join Lines`

---

- #### ONLINE TOOLS :

I have also found an online tool where you could just paste the text and it would remove all the line breaks . Check to see if this tool helps -> https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php  or https://codebeautify.org/remove-line-breaks .You could find many such tools online where you could just paste your text and it will remove all the line breaks for you.

Answer (score 2):

### Using VS Code

[image]

### Using awk

Assuming your text is in a file called `break.txt`, and the code below is in a file called `break.awk, then the follwing command will work:

```
awk -f break.awk break.txt > edited.txt
```

The output will be in `output.txt` and your original file will be unchanged.

```
BEGIN {
  line = ""
}

{
  line = line " " $1
}

END {
  print line
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in any of the more advanced text editors that support regular expressions or some form of control characters by simply replacing `\n` with a space. It would help to know which text editor you are using, but generally any of them should use the same, or very similar, syntax (YMMV: depending on the OS, some use `\n`, others use `\r\n`). To take care of any OS differences, you can use the Regular Expression to match EOL: `(\r\n|\n|\r)` and replace instances with a space.

-- Edit: I see this was tagged with `word`. You can replace `^p` with a space ( ) character and it will do what you want.