# Convert multiple lines to single line using RStudio text editor

Tags: r, rstudio

Does the RStudio text editor have a simple automated way to convert this:

```
c(
"097",
"085",
"041",
"055"
)
```

to this: `c("097", "085", "041", "055")`?

There are answers for other text editors (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158789/convert-multiple-lines-to-single-line-using-text-editor)), but I'm looking for a solution specific to RStudio.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not an automated solution per se, but many people don't know about RStudio's support for multiline cursors. Just hold Alt (Option on Mac) and drag across multiple lines, then press backspace a few times:

[image]

Also very handy for adding commas or closing parentheses to multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 5):

The multi-line cursor answer from @jdobres is how I'd do it, but you should also be aware of the excellent `datapasta` package, which can do what you're asking and a whole lot more. A very helpful add-in for RStudio, imo.

Comment: Can the `datapasta` add-in convert a dataframe and displayed it into one line ?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @rdelrossi, `datapasta` is a helpful package for editing and styling text/code. On Mac, once you install the package (also installs as an add-in), then you have access to several keyboard shortcuts. For example, to convert a vector from vertical to horizontal, you could use `vector_paste()` or use the keyboard shortcut, which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

[image]

You can read about some of the other functions and shortcuts (e.g., paste as vertical vector) at [Typical Datapasta Usage with Rstudio](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dput`:

```r
dput(c(
"097",
"085",
"041",
"055"
))
#> c("097", "085", "041", "055")
```

It is also possible to set-up a code formatting add-in that you can bind to keyboard shortcuts by installing the `styler` package.

Comment: This is good to know, but I'm hoping that there's a way to do it in the text editor itself (akin to Edit -> Line Operations -> Join Lines in Notepad ++).

Answer (score 3):

RStudio has a find/replace feature. You can replace new line characters `\n` with spaces   for this effect. Make sure you have the "regex" box checked for it to work.

[image]

Comment: Hmm ... this isn't working for me (with or without the Regex box checked). RStudio finds no occurrences.

Comment: I would like to accept this answer, since it seems like it should work and is closer in spirit to the question than the other (excellent) answers. But I can't accept if it doesn't work and, judging from the votes on the above comment, it appears that I'm not the only person who can't implement it.

Comment: Maybe it only works on the Mac version? Works well for me using RStudio 2021.09.0+351 "Ghost Orchid" Release for macOS.